# How can I tell what filter size to use for a certain size image?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I was developing a GAN to generate 48x48 images of faces. However, the generator makes strange images no matter how much training is done, and no matter how much the discriminator thinks it's fake. This leads me to believe that it is an architectural problem.

---

untrained output

[image: untrained]

After 25 epochs

[image: 25 epochs]

The problem is obvious. Squares generating in patterns instead of random pixels, as would be expected from an untrained GAN.

This problem appears to be related to the filter size of the deconvolution layers in the generator, but I'm not sure how.

This is an image from a 5x5 kernel size

[image]

My question is:

1. Why is this happening? What effect is the filter size having on the images that causes this sort of pattern
2. How can I tell what size filter to use in relation to the image size or other parameter?

Models:

```py
generator = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(4*4*32, input_shape=(100,), use_bias=False),
    keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    
    keras.layers.Reshape((4, 4, 32)),
    
    SpectralNormalization(keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same", use_bias=False)),
    keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    
    SpectralNormalization(keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same", use_bias=False)),
    keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    
    SpectralNormalization(keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(3, (2, 2), strides=(3, 3), padding="same", use_bias=False)),
    keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    
    SpectralNormalization(keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(3, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same", use_bias=False)),

    
    
    
])


discriminator = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), input_shape=(96, 96, 3), padding="same"),
    keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    
    
    SpectralNormalization(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")),
    keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    
    SpectralNormalization(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")),
    keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    
    SpectralNormalization(keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")),
    keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    
    SpectralNormalization(keras.layers.Conv2D(8, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")),
    keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    

    
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
    
])
```

The training loop was taken from the [Tensorflow GAN tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/dcgan#define_the_training_loop)

```py
cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()

def discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output):
    real_loss = cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(real_output), real_output)
    fake_loss = cross_entropy(tf.zeros_like(fake_output), fake_output)
    total_loss = real_loss + fake_loss
    return total_loss

def generator_loss(fake_output):
    return cross_entropy(tf.ones_like(fake_output), fake_output)

generator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)
discriminator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4)

@tf.function
def train_step(images):
    noise = tf.random.normal([32, 100])

    with tf.GradientTape() as gen_tape, tf.GradientTape() as disc_tape:
        generated_images = generator(noise, training=True)

        real_output = discriminator(images, training=True)
        fake_output = discriminator(generated_images, training=True)

        gen_loss = generator_loss(fake_output)
        disc_loss = discriminator_loss(real_output, fake_output)

    gradients_of_generator = gen_tape.gradient(gen_loss, generator.trainable_variables)
    gradients_of_discriminator = disc_tape.gradient(disc_loss, discriminator.trainable_variables)

    generator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_generator, generator.trainable_variables))
    discriminator_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients_of_discriminator, discriminator.trainable_variables))
```

Comment: I don't think filter size is the issue here, stacked 3x3 kernels will work for just about any net. Can you generate a single batch of several images and show them here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is caused when larger `strides` are introduced at the final layers

> Consider a 1d case:

```
input values             = i1 | i2 | i3 

transposeConv1(k=2,s=3)     
weights (k=2)            = w1 | w2 |
initialization           = 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0 | 0  | 0
output                   =i1w1|i1w2| 0  |i2w1|i2w2| 0 |i3w1|i3w2
                         = o1 | o2 | 0  | o4 | o5 | 0 | o7 | o8 
It introduces blockiness with zeros in between

Consider the last layer together with the previous layer
transposeConv1(k=2,s=2)     
weights (k=2)            = w1 | w2 |
initialization           = 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0 | 0  | 0  | ...
output                   =o1w1|o1w2|o2w1|o2w2| 0  | 0 |o4w1|o4w2| ...
Now more zeros are introduced
```

Comment: I tried it, but the problem remains. Should I try a bigger stride length?

Comment: I'd try using a stride of 1 instead

Comment: @rvinas That worked! If you would explain how this worked in an answer, I would be glad to mark it as correct.

Comment: That's what one can infer from my above answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are supposed to use SpectralNormalization in the generator. It is meant to smooth out the learning for WGAN and should only be used in the discriminator. [SNGAN Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.05957.pdf)

You keep getting checkered patterns because ConvTranspose generates them. To counter them, your kernel size should be divisible by stride in ConvTranspose.

Comment: I tried this, removing the SpectralNormalization layers from the generator and made the kernel size divisible by strides, k=(6, 6), s=(2, 2). However, after training begins, the checkered patterns return.

Comment: You would have to train for many epochs since you're using SpectralNormalization. It basically helps in training the generator for more epochs. It kind of slows down the learning of the discriminator. (This is not exactly the correct explanation, just something I have noticed by experimenting). Use kernel_size=4 and strides of 2.
Also, I recommend using the WGAN-GP loss with SpectralNorm.

Comment: Would you happen to have a Tensorflow implementation for WGAN? I haven't been able to find any

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is your weight init. Can you print your input layer weights before and after training? So generator.get_weights(), then train, then generator.get_weights() again.

Could you also do the same with your output layer of the generator?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for WGAN with Gradient Penalty

```
BATCH_SIZE = 32
latent_dim = 128
c_lambda = 10

# Will reuse this seed overtime to visualize generated image at each epoch
seed = tf.random.normal([4, latent_dim])

def get_generator_model():
...
return model

generator = get_generator_model()

noise = tf.random.normal([1, 128])
generated_image = generator(noise, training=False)

def get_discriminator_model():
...
return model

discriminator = get_discriminator_model()
decision = discriminator(generated_image)

class WGAN(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, discriminator, generator, latent_dim, discriminator_extra_steps=3):
    super(WGAN, self).__init__()
    
    self.discriminator = discriminator
    self.generator = generator
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim
    self.d_steps = discriminator_extra_steps

  def compile(self, d_optimizer, g_optimizer, d_loss_fn, g_loss_fn):
    super(WGAN, self).compile()
  
    self.d_optimizer = d_optimizer
    self.g_optimizer = g_optimizer
    self.d_loss_fn = d_loss_fn
    self.g_loss_fn = g_loss_fn

  def gradient_penalty(self, batch_size, real_images, fake_images):
    epsilon = tf.random.normal(real_images[0].shape, 1, 1, 1)
    mixed_images = real_images * epsilon + fake_images * (1 - epsilon)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      tape.watch(mixed_images)
      mixed_scores = self.discriminator(mixed_images)

    grads = tape.gradient(mixed_scores, mixed_images)
    # norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(grads), axis=[1, 2, 3]))
    norm = tf.norm(grads, axis=0)
    gp = tf.reduce_mean((norm - 1.0) ** 2)
    return gp
    
  def train_step(self, real_images):
    if isinstance(real_images, tuple):
      real_images = real_images[0]

    batch_size = tf.shape(real_images)[0]

    # Train the discriminator
    for i in range(self.d_steps):
      random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim))
      with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        fake_images = self.generator(random_latent_vectors, training=True)
        fake_logits = self.discriminator(fake_images, training=True)
        real_logits = self.discriminator(real_images, training=True)
        
        gp = self.gradient_penalty(batch_size, real_images, fake_images)
        
        d_loss = self.d_loss_fn(real_img=real_logits, fake_img=fake_logits, gp=gp)

      d_gradient = tape.gradient(d_loss, self.discriminator.trainable_variables)
      self.d_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(d_gradient, self.discriminator.trainable_variables))

    # Train the generator
    random_latent_vectors = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch_size, self.latent_dim))
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      generated_images = self.generator(random_latent_vectors, training=True)
      gen_img_logits = self.discriminator(generated_images, training=True)
      g_loss = self.g_loss_fn(gen_img_logits)

    gen_gradient = tape.gradient(g_loss, self.generator.trainable_variables)
    self.g_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gen_gradient, self.generator.trainable_variables))
    
    return {"d_loss": d_loss, "g_loss": g_loss}

class GANMonitor(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def __init__(self, num_img=4, latent_dim=128):
    self.num_img = num_img
    self.latent_dim = latent_dim

  def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    generated_images = self.model.generator(seed)
    generated_images = (generated_images * 127.5) + 127.5

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))

    for i in range(self.num_img):
      plt.subplot(2, 2, i+1)
      plt.imshow(generated_images[i, :, :, 0], cmap='gray')
      plt.axis('off')
    plt.savefig('image_at_epoch_{:04d}.png'.format(epoch))
    plt.show()

generator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
    learning_rate=0.0002, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.999)

discriminator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
    learning_rate=0.0002, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.999)

def discriminator_loss(real_img, fake_img, gp):
    real_loss = tf.reduce_mean(real_img)
    fake_loss = tf.reduce_mean(fake_img)
    return fake_loss - real_loss + c_lambda * gp

def generator_loss(fake_img):
    return -tf.reduce_mean(fake_img)

epochs = 250

# callback
cbk = GANMonitor(num_img=4, latent_dim=latent_dim)

wgan = WGAN(discriminator,
                  generator,
            latent_dim=latent_dim,
            discriminator_extra_steps=3)

wgan.compile(d_optimizer=discriminator_optimizer,
             g_optimizer=generator_optimizer,
             g_loss_fn=generator_loss,
             d_loss_fn=discriminator_loss)

history = wgan.fit(dataset, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=epochs, callbacks=[cbk])
```